# lombok @NonNull on Field not readable using getAnnotations

Tags: reflection, annotations, lombok

Example:

```
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class A {
    //
    // RecordRootable fields
    //
    @NonNull
    private UUID a;
}
```

Looking at the class file the @NonNull annotation seems to be present if the IntelliJ decompiler is not lying.

Now we want to read the annotation from the Field using Field.getAnnotations or something similar at runtime but nothing is found.

Is there any particular method I can use to read this annotation?

Is there anything extra I need to add to the annotation to be able to read it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the Annotation has
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
instead of 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
so they can't be read reflectively

Comment: Furthermore, Lombok removes all its annotations during compilation, because there should not be any runtime dependency to Lombok in the compiled code.